# always redirecting to Login page when opening website via http

Tags: c#, http, model-view-controller, https

1 At first I open my website via `https://mywebsite.com` and then I can login normally

2 After that I delete `https://` from the browser url and add `http://` instead.

3 Then refresh the page and it redirects me to the login page

4 When I type my credentials again and try to login (but via `http://`) it always redirects me to the same login page. And at the end of the url I can see `Login?ReturnUrl=%2FClientDashboard%2FList`. 
I have `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on my `Login` action and it works fine with `https://`.

What can be the reason of such kind of behavior?

Comment: Not sure enough to post as an answer, but check your IIS or IIS Express to see if enforce HTTPS is enabled. I've got a fliting memory that there is something like that, but not sure. Could also be your browser, doesn't Chrome enforce HTTPS now?

Comment: I've tried to do the same in Edge and it worked normally. So the problem is connected with the chrome, I think it has cached something, found a related post here but it didn't work for me 
https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

Comment: gilliduck thanks a lot. You are right about 'Chrome enforce HTTPS'. I've cleared cookies and other site data, and now everything is ok. You can post your comment and I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome by default enforces HTTPS. You'll need to disable that there and/or clear data so that it doesn't try to keep redirecting.

Or just use a different browser that doesn't enforce.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using asp.net core, if it's the case, have a look at Startup.cs =>

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

There might be a line of code like this

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Just remove it and you can use without https

Comment: I'm using `Asp.net MVC 5.2.2.0` not `Core` and I've searched in my solution for `UseHttpsRedirection` but didn't get anything.